# How ASP.NET Core APIs convert ActionResult<T> to T in action methods

Tags: c#, .net-core

As an example look at below code which is a an API action:

```
[HttpGet("send")]
public ActionResult<string> Send()
{
    if (IsAuthorized())
    {
        return "Ok";
    }
    return Unauthorized(); // is of type UnauthorizedResult -> StatusCodeResult -> ActionResult -> IActionResult
}
```

My question is how this data conversion is happening here? How doesn't the compiler fail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible due to a language feature called operator overloading which allows for the creation of custom operators. ActionResult has such an [implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs):

```
public sealed class ActionResult<TValue> : IConvertToActionResult
{
       public TValue Value { get; }

       public ActionResult(TValue value)
       {
            /* error checking code removed */
            Value = value;
       }

       public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(TValue value)
       {
           return new ActionResult<TValue>(value);
       }
}
```

`public static implicit operator` I.e. this method provides the logic for `TValue` to be **implicitly** casted to type ActionResult. It's a very simple method that creates a new `ActionResult` with the value set to a public variable called `Value`. This method makes this legal:

```
ActionResult<int> result = 10; <-- // same as new ActionResult(10)
```

This essentially creates syntatic sugar for what you do in the Action methods to be legal.